# Fixing corroded contact surfaces on PCB

Tags: current, repair, copper, corrosion

Looking at a Seagate HDD that no longer connects. The motor is running, but does not show in devices. The disk has production date is 12361 (2012-03-05).

Before having a look inside I checked out the PCB.

I noticed the contact points was rather corroded. It has only been inside computer cabinet and exposed to the environment therein. I scraped off some of the corrosion and reassembled - but no change.

Decided to have a closer look at the board etc:

Board:

[image: PCB HDD]

<sup>Fig PCB-1.</sup>

There is a 3 point contact surface for the motor and a 18 point for the arm.

---

Looking closer at the contact points. First the ones on the HDD looks OK:

| Motor 3pin | Arm 18pin (bad pic, is 18) |
| --- | --- |
| [image: HDD pins motor] <sup>Fig PIN-1.</sup> | [image: HDD pins arm] <sup>Fig PIN-2.</sup> |

but the PCB looks worse:

| Motor 3pt | Motor 3pt |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Contact area motor I] <sup>Fig MOT-1.</sup> | [image: Contact area motor II] <sup>Fig MOT-2.</sup> |

| Arm 18pt | Arm 18pt |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Arm18pt I] <sup>Fig ARM-1.</sup> | [image: Arm18pt II] <sup>Fig ARM-2.</sup> |
| [image: Arm18pt III] <sup>Fig ARM-3.</sup> | [image: Arm18pt IV] <sup>Fig ARM-4.</sup> |

---

My questions are if this is *normal*, looks like a lot of corrosion, and if trying to fix the contact-surface could be a good idea. The screw-holes also show quite some wear.

If so: how would one approach this? Simply scraping off?

Comment: Do you intend to recover disk data or do you want to repair it for general use?

Comment: @Jeroen3: I want to try to recover the data, - but as HDD repair is so expensive it's a DIY project.

Comment: once the plating is gone, it will corrode much faster the next time. You could add a solder layer but that won't be that good a contract surface. Also agree w/ answer below, that it doesn't look that bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repair tech here. If you don't actually connect anything to those pins, it shouldn't actually matter. And I can confidently say this is not severe corrosion and it should work. I see many laptops that have components that look a lot worse and they work totally OK, it's just surface corrosion which you can find in any laptop over 4 years old in perfect working condition.

While 100% confidence is impossible (sh happens), I firmly believe the problem is not in these contacts. You can try to tin those pads if you wish, some light scraping with the soldering tip as you tin them (not too hot, 330C or so, hotter can tear the pads off if corroded; likely 280+ will be ok).

Also, I'm concerned by your "before having the look inside". Unless you're HDD data recovery expert, looking inside = kissing goodbye to any data you had there (actually, to the entire HDD; it's dead). Immediately. As soon as a dustling from the air lands on the platter, it's ciao.

I would start by checking if it shows up in Windows "Create and format disk partitions" program, or in disk utility on mac. (Or on the almighty linux, but it's beyond my paygrade).

Comment: Hi. Not sure what you mean by *“If you don't actually connect anything to those pins, it shouldn't actually matter.”* - they connect to the PCB. As for looking inside – yes, I'm aware of the risks. Have read various documents + there are some good videos on YT (yes I know ;P). Have also mailed with some people at forensics repair firms for tips and hints. More of an issue is having proper HW/software for the post process + getting a spare drive for parts. Considering https://rapidspar.com/ (as a full PC-3000 is to costly).

Comment: That quote means "do you actually connect something to these very pads physically?" If you don't connect anything RIGHT THERE onto the corrosion, then it's totally irrelevant

Comment: Yes. They connect to `Fig PIN-1.` and `Fig PIN-2.`. The PCB is fastened with screws on the HDD itself where those pins are part of the interior (contacts for motor 3pin + contacts for the arm 18pin). No plugs. Simply pins to surface (where surface is PCB).

Comment: Then try gently scraping with the knife until the pad (well, every pad) is mostly shiny. Very gently. You won't damage anything, don't worry, just no need to scrape off any more metal that you need to. I still think it's not the reason of the problem, but every now and then basic solutions work

Comment: Ended up using my Maped Mini Technic Eraser :P, It worked surprisingly well.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrtmh.jpg – not that it helped the HDD working. Next step is to check components.

Comment: You can get an exact duplicate board (purchase another drive) and exchange boards, that may help you recover your data. When you do start to recover the data do it in a single operation, starting and stopping can cause it to not work again. Wit this in mind be sure your target device has enough room to hold all of the drive data. I have done this several times most of the time it was successful.

Comment: @Gil: Yes. Issue can be that replacement board does not have the correct ROM data. One might have to move the components from old to new. I have found an exact match on donordrives.com (model, part-number, firmware, pcb-sticker and pcb-number) but want to check around a bit more. Would rather want a replacement drive - as in not only the board. Second issue is the access part. Want to find a solution on Linux where I can control how the OS probe the disk, - so that it does not start probing it once I connect. Ideally a lower level control. Perhaps going Pi or arduino. But have to read up on it